# How to resolve why attempting to publish an SNS message from a Lambda function that is connected to a VPC hangs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

I have a very simply Lambda function:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snsTopicArn="arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:REDACTED:keiths-test-topic"
    snsClient = boto3.client('sns')
    message="This is a test"
    print("before snsClient.publish")
    response = snsClient.publish(TopicArn=snsTopicArn, Message=message, Subject="This is a test")
    print(response)
    return(response)
```

When I run it, it hangs at the snsClient.publish() statement until the function times out. I've increate the timeout to over a minute, and it doesn't help. The Lambda function is connected to my VPC, which does have an Internet Gateway so I would think it wouldn't have any problems getting to the appropriate AWS API endpoint. If I run the same function, without connecting it to my VPC though, it does run as expected. So, the problem does seem to have something to do with running it from my VPC.

Note that if I run the exact same code from an EC2 instance running in the same VPC, in the same subnet, it runs just fine.

Of course, this is just a code segment of a larger piece of code, and that code also reads from an S3 bucket, but for some reason it hangs if it tries to read an object that doesn't exist. I don't know if the two hangs are related or not.

I created an SNS VPC endpoint that is attached to my VPC and subnet. The SG associated with it has an inbound rule to allow all traffic from the VPC's CIDR and has an unrestricted outbound rule.

I've tried increasing the Lambda function timeout. Didn't change anything.

I have tried giving the Lambda function all the SNS permissions, thinking it might be a permissions problem, but that didn't change anything.

If someone has any ideas what could be causing this, and/or what to look at to try to diagnose it, I would greatly appreciate hearing from you. Thanks!

Comment: What do the security groups attached to the lambda itself look like?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to connect the Lambda function to a VPC (eg to access another resource that is in the VPC)? If not, then there is no benefit to attaching the function to a VPC.

Comment: The SG has an inbound rule of "All TCP 0 - 65535 10.0.0.0/8" rule in it (and the CIDR for the VPC is 10.0.0.0/16) and outbound rule of: "All All 0.0.0.0/0".  The reason it is in a VPC is because it has to access a service that is only accessible from within the VPC. Note, above is just a code segment, that duplicates this issue, of the real Lambda function I am running. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out what the problem is. Even though my VPC had an Internet Gateway, you must create a SNS endpoint and when you create it, you must enable "Private DNS names." This requires you to "Enable DNS hostname" on the VPC. In my environment I didn't have "DNS hostname" enabled on my VPC (the default setting), so when I created the endpoint it wouldn't allow me to enable "private DNS names" so I didn't do that. Apparently that is how the Lambda function routes the SNS request to the endpoint, by following the DNS resolution of the endpoint. Once I enabled the two settings, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, SNS is like S3 a global service, so you did not need to attach it to your custom VPC on your lambda function to push to an SNS Topic to clarify it :)

I did not know your VPC settings, it can be many things but when you say it's working on an EC2 instance but not into your Lambda functions it sounds like a VPC issue.

So what I will try if you do not need the custom VPC on your Lambda for any reasons is to give it a try without that VPC and see what happens.

Your syntax looks fine so based on your information I will give it a shot, normally I create Lambda and SNS topics from AWS CDK code because its will allow me if i get stuck to get faster help because I can share my infrastructure code so a little tip for you :)

Its required to have the right policy bound to your Lambda function, as default the IAM policy did not have right to something, so find the policy and allow to publish into SNS Topics in general a sample code like this for your policy

```
{
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":"sns:Publish",
    "Resource":"*"
  }]
}
```

This policy will allow you to use publish into all sns topic, the recommendation when you confirm its working to change the resource with your sns topic arn for secuerty reason.

Read more about users permissions to publish to SNS Topic here on AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.iam.permissions.html

Comment: Thanks ParisNakitaKejser, I appreciate your help.

The real Lambda function polls a service, that is only accessible from within the VPC, to get status. This is why it has to run in the VPC. The service it polls doesn't have the capability to send SNS messages, hence why I want to use the Lambda function find and report on issues.

I'm not following why the program can work in my EC2 instance and not the Lambda function, when they are both running in the same network.  I would appreciate any thoughts you have here. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that I did confirm that both the EC2 instance and the Lambda function have the same security group, and that the security group has an inbound rule of "All TCP 0 - 65535 10.0.0.0/8" rule in it (and the CIDR for the VPC is 10.0.0.0/16) and outbound rule of: "All  All   0.0.0.0/0".

Comment: Okat make sens about the VPC, did you have give the lambda function right policy based on you IAM to publish to your SNS Topic? - i will update my answer with it

Comment: Yes, out of desperation, I gave it full SNS permissions.

Comment: Slight correction, I gave my real function as much SNS permissions as I could, for this test function, I did just give you sns:Publish. Here is the actual role
```{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}```